# International travel with pets with transfer - paperwork for third country?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, paperwork, pets

We are travelling from USA to France with pets.  Most affordable tickets will require transfer through a third country, e.g. Aeroflot will go through Moscow SVO.  In these situations is it required to get an import/export permit for the third country as well, in addition to the permits for the destination country?

Comment: I would think you should instead try to minimize the time your pets have to be in transit and fly directly to France. Then the connection problem goes away. Cabin or cargo? Or would you break the trip in the third country?

Comment: @mkennedy The problem never goes away because all affordable options transit within a third country.  Direct options multiply the costs (which are already increased due to travelling with animals and other timing constraints).  They travel in the cabin, the cargo hold is not safe.

Answer (score 5):

If you are flying in and out of Russia on Aeroflot and if your pet is traveling with you in the cabin or as checked baggage and if your layover is less than 2 hours, [then you will transit the airport and not enter Russia](http://www.pettravel.com/airline_pet_rules/aeroflot.cfm).

If your layover in Russia is over 2 hours, then you'll have to re-check your pet, so you'll have to comply with Russian import regulations ([source](http://www.pettravel.com/immigration/russia.cfm)):

- Rabies vaccination must be performed between 30 days and 12 months before the departure.
- A licensed veterinarian must complete a Veterinary Certificate for Russia indicating that the animals are clinically healthy and vaccinated against rabies.  Although it is not required, it is recommended that a USDA or CFIA licensed veterinarian complete the form and you have it endorsed by the USDA or CFIA if traveling from the United States or Canada. If you are traveling to Russia from another country with your pet, the Governing Authority in your country responsibile for the import and export of animals should endorse your forms.
- A copy of the Rabies Certificate should also be included for endorsement.

This completes a pet passport for your dog or cat to enter Russia.

See also [the corresponding Российская газета article](http://www.rg.ru/2012/01/18/vettranzit-dok.html) for other pet transit rules in Russia.

Comment: What if the transit is longer than 2 hours but less than 24 hours?

Comment: I added information on this case in my answer: you'll have to comply with Russian pet import regulations.